# How to show database contents in jTable?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

So I'm trying to get data from my database and putting it into a jTable. It works correctly in that it shows the first set of results, but then it just keeps repeating the same records. Anyone have any idea what's wrong with it? Thanks in advance!

```
void Flight(){
try{

    int x = 0;
    while (rs.next()){
    jTable1.setValueAt(flightID, x, 0);
    jTable1.setValueAt(departdate, x, 1);
    jTable1.setValueAt(departtime, x, 2);
    jTable1.setValueAt(destination, x, 3);
    jTable1.setValueAt(arrivdate, x, 4);
    jTable1.setValueAt(arrivtime, x, 5);

    x++;
    rs.next();
    }
}
catch(SQLException err) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(AdminWindow.this, err.getMessage());
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you never change the values in the variables "flightID", "departdate", etc.. Invoking rs.next() won't update the values.

So inside the loop you need to get the values from the ResultSet. Somethink like:

```
//jTable1.setValueAt(flightID, x, 0);
jTable1.setValueAt(rs.getObject(1), x, 0);
```

Also you invoke rs.next() twice so you will be skipping rows of data.

However, it is not a good idea to use the `setValueAt(...)` method to update the TableModel because you don't know in advance how many rows there are so you don't know how big to create the table. Instead it is better to create a row of data and then add a row of data to the TableModel. This way the model is dynamic.

An example of this approach can be found in the `Table From Database Example` code found in [Table From Database](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/).

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you very much for the help! I'll take a look at that Table example you linked.